# EVAL IN C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have dynamic content in a content placeholder placed in a datalist that is bound to an object datasource. the problem is i need to check the value of the EVAL. here is the code:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
                DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333">
                <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                <ItemTemplate>


                    <a href="<%# Eval("VendorLink") %>"> <%# Eval("Vendor") %></a>
                    <br />
                    <a href="<%#    Eval("TitleLink") %> "><%# Eval("Title") %></a>
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="DescLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Desc") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="DetailsLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Details") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="RptIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RptID") %>' />
                    <br />

                    <asp:Label ID="LinksLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Links") %>' />
                    <br />
                    <br />

                </ItemTemplate>
                <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            </asp:DataList>
```

i want to say

```
<%if(Eval("RptID") =="SomeString") { Eval("rtpid") = "Pass");}%>
```

i need the checkup to be at the aspx page and not the aspx.cs page! how to perform the checkup??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check like below :

```
<%# Eval("VenderLink") == "somestring" ? "p %>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do like this:

```
<%# (Eval("UserName") == "Test 1") ? "no.png" : "yes.gif" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
<%# string.Compare(Eval("RptID").ToString(), "SomeString") == 0 ? Eval("RptID") : "Nothing" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap your expression in single quotes, otherwise it's invalid SGML. The parser thinks the attribute ends on the second `"`.

```
<a href='<%# Eval("VendorLink") %>'> <%# Eval("Vendor") %></a>
```

You can't use `IF` contructs in the binding context, only binding expressions. You can always hook [`ItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemdatabound.aspx) instead and put your logic on server side (or move it to a method in code-behind).

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{       
        var descLabel= e.Item.FindControl("RptIDLabel") as Label;
        var data = (MyDataType)e.Item.DataItem; 
        if (data.RptID == "SomeString")
        {
           descLabel.Text = "Pass";
        }
        ...       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Eval("RptID")` it's a function, so you can't do `Eval("rtpid")` = "something";

If you need to write logic you can always create a protected or public function  in code behind that will return you the string you need.

You can call the function like this

```
<%# TransformString(Eval("RptID")) %>
```

and the function in the code behind

```
protected string TransformString(object rptid)
{
     //some code goes here
}
```